# Android: json_encode to array - non associative array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

My php file has this output:

```
echo json_encode(array("value0","value1","value2"));
```

How can I get this response as an array in Android?

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                       
String[] resultArray = ?
```

I want to have:

```
resultArray[0] --> value0
resultArray[1] --> value1
resultArray[2] --> value2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ResponseHandler first, then you will have response in string and then convert to array by following procedure

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
JSONArray test = new JSONArray(responseBody);
String[] resultingArray = test.join(",").split(",");
```